# How to display content for a Taxonomy Vocabulary?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I am using Drupal 8.

I have a Vocabulary called Fruit which contains terms:

Apple
Banana
Orange

I can go to page for term Apple and I can find all the content which was tagged with apple there. I want to create a page with all content tagged under Fruit as well. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Use Views? Or you can use a module like Taxonomy Views Integrator - which still uses Views.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at creating views you can start by watching 
as many as the following to get the idea:

https://www.google.com/search?q=drupal+8+how+to+create+a+view&source=lnms&tbm=vid